# how to show a jQuery ui DialogBox in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, razor

I´m working on a MVC ASP.NET project and I would like to use a dialog box using jQuery ui every time a user clicks a specific button, was pretty easy for me in PHP but now in ASP.NEt I'm kinda stuck and cannot find the reason why, this is my code and the beginning of the page

```
@model GFC_Site.Models.UserModel.RegistroUser

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Registro";
}

@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")

@*I added the jquery, jquery ui and its due css via this way too in case the bundle created by myself has errors*@

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/dialog.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.cupertino.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $("#submit").click(function () {           
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            height: 170,
            width: 350,
            show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
            modal: true,
            draggable: true,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();

            },
            buttons: {
                "OK": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    window.location.href = url;
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

and this is my form, it has more fields but I just show one, the button and the div I want to show

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Registro", "Login", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form", id="nuevo" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NIT, new { @class = "sr-only control-label col-md-2" })

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">digite NIT Proveedor</div>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NIT, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "text" })
                </div>
                <p class="text-danger"> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NIT)</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <button type="submit" id="submit" value="Registrarse" class="btn btn-primary" @*onclick="return confirm('Desea ingresar información de registro?')"*@ >
                    Registrarse
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="dialog-confirm" style="display: none">
        <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span> Are you sure to delete? </p>
    </div>
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your razor view looks fine, but your JavaScript is only instantiating the dialog every time the submit button is clicked.  If you want, you can move the dialog instantiation out of the submit click callback, and replace that with a `$("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");` call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // instantiate the dialog on document ready
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        height: 170,
        width: 350,
        show: {
            effect: 'drop',
            direction: 'up'
        },
        modal: true,
        draggable: true,
        open: function(event, ui) {
            $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
        },
        buttons: {
            "OK": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                window.location.href = url;
             },
        "Cancel": function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    });

    $("#submit").click(function() {
      // open the dialog on the submit button click
      $('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open');
    });
});
```

Comment: hello, I did what you suggested but doesn´t showed up the modal dialog box yet

Comment: You might be experiencing a load order issue.  Can you try moving the `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>` line before your bundle calls?  If the bundle version of jquery ui wins out, the base jquery js file hasn't been loaded ahead of it and any calls to it would fail.  Beyond that, any errors that you're seeing in the browser's developer tools console could help us track down the issue

Comment: I was thinking exactly the same and order the scripts in the layout page in the  next order:                                                                                <script src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("/js/bootstrap.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js")"></script>      but still not working

Comment: You may need to provide the `~` in the `Url.Content` call since it expects a relative path.  According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content(v=vs.118).aspx) if the string passed to the method is not a relative path, it just returns the string it was given.  Since all your other scripts are loaded with relative paths, this might be the problem

Comment: I Just did as you recommented but still doesn't work, cannot understand what could be the problem